# C passing a value through a function changes that value in the function

Tags: c

my function does not grab the value from main.

```
    typedef struct {
        struct node *grip;

    }PoolQueue;


    struct node{
        char *temp;
        int *data;
        struct node *next;
    }node;

    PoolQueue *PQcreatePoolQueue(){
        PoolQueue *queue;
        queue = malloc(sizeof(PoolQueue));
        queue->grip = NULL;
        return queue;
    }

   int main()
    {
        char x[] = "";
        printf("Hello world!\n");
        PoolQueue *q = PQcreatePoolQueue();
        scanf("%s", &x);
        PQaddSingle(x, q);
        return 0;
    }

    void PQaddSingle(char *item, PoolQueue *queue){
        if(queue->grip == NULL) printf("It is null");

    }
```

When I call the function PQaddSingle the queue->grip I created in main isn't NULL anymore.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of your badly formed scanf storage location. You're scanning into an item that has zero bytes to store data... this causes undefined results which, in this case, are likely overwriting your value of `q` - apparently with a value you can still read. Try printing the value of `q` before and after your `scanf` to see what I mean.

Better yet, declare the length of `x` to be longer than the input (including line termination and NULL termination) will be!